# Compute Absolute values of N integer combinations Combinations

Tags: c++

For a N number (a..N) I am finding set of all combinations in the following way:

```
void create_print_combinations(int *t, int x, int n) {
    if(x == 0) {
        char p [2 * r + 2];
        memset (p, 0, 2 * r +2);
        for (int j=c;j>0;j--)
            if(j == c)
                sprintf(p, "%d", t[j]);
            else
                sprintf(p, "%s,%d", p,t[j]);
            print_combi(p);
    } else {
         for (int i= n; i < r; i++) {
             t[x] = a[i];
             create_print_combinations(t, x-1, i+1);
         }
    }
}
```

So a call to function like:

```
int main() {
    unsigned long int start=0, end=0;
    printf ("\nEnter the a positive integer N:");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    start=time(NULL);
    a = new int[r];
    for (int i = 0;i<r;i++)
    a[i]=i+1;
    for(int j=1;j<=r;j++) {
        a1 = new int[j];
        c=j;
        create_print_combinations(a1, c, 0);
        delete[] a1;
    }
    end=time(NULL);
    printf("Total time taken = %llu\n" , end - start);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me combinations like for N=4:

Enter the a positive integer N:4

```
Combo : [1]
Combo : [2]
Combo : [3]
Combo : [4]
Combo : [1,2]
Combo : [1,3]
Combo : [1,4]
Combo : [2,3]
Combo : [2,4]
Combo : [3,4]
Combo : [1,2,3]
Combo : [1,2,4]
Combo : [1,3,4]
Combo : [2,3,4]
Combo : [1,2,3,4]
```

Now my tasks is to fond the absolute values of all combinations like:

For Combo [1,2,3,4] it should be:

```
1+2+3+4 = abs(1+2+3+4)
1+2+3-4 = abs(1+2+3-4)
1+2-3-4 = ..
1-2-3+4 = ...
```

Ans so on

I am trying the below logic:

```
while(pos > 0)
{
for(int a=0; a < i; a++)
{
if(a==0)
sprintf(p,"%d", t[a]);
else if(a == pos)
sprintf(p,"%s%c%d",p, minus, t[a]);
else
sprintf(p,"%s%c%d",p, plus, t[a]);
}
print(p);
memset (p , 0, 2 * r +2);
pos --;
}
```

But I beleiev I am doing something wrong as all sets are not getting printed. I am unable to frame the logic though I feel I am near to completion. Below is my whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int *a;
int *a1;
int r;
int c;
unsigned long int no =1;

int stoi(char *var)
{
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
int n3 = 0;
char sign=0;
while(*var)
{
if(isspace(*var))
{
var++;
continue;
}
while(*var >= '0' && *var <= '9')
{
n1=(n1*10) + (*var - '0');
var++;
continue;
}
if(sign == '+')
{
n2=n2+n1;
n1=0;
}
else if(sign == '-')
{
n2=n2 - n1;
n1=0;
}
if(*var == '+' || *var == '-')
{
if(sign == 0)
{
n2=n1;
n1=0;
}
sign = *var;
}
var++;
}
if(sign == 0)
return abs(n1);
return abs(n2);
}

void print(char* var)
{
printf("[Combo %llu.] %s = %d\n" , no++, var, stoi(var));
}

void print_combi(char * a)
{
int t[c];
char *x = NULL;
char *y = a;
int i=0;
while((x=strchr(y, ',')) != NULL)
{
*x = '\0';
t[i++]=atoi(y);
y=x+1;
}
t[i++]=atoi(y);
int count =0;
int loop = 0;
char p [2 * r + 2];
memset (p , 0, 2 * r +2);
char plus = '+';
char minus = '-';
for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
{
if(k==1)
{
plus =  '-';
minus = '+';
}
if(i>1)
{
for(int a=0; a < i; a++)
{
if(a==0)
sprintf(p,"%d", t[a]);
else
sprintf(p,"%s%c%d",p, plus, t[a]);
}
}
else if(i==1)
{
sprintf(p,"%d", t[i-1]);
print(p);
break;
}
print(p);
memset (p , 0, 2 * r +2);
if(i==2)
continue;
if(i==3 && k ==1)
break;
int pos = i-1;
while(pos > 0)
{
for(int a=0; a < i; a++)
{
if(a==0)
sprintf(p,"%d", t[a]);
else if(a == pos)
sprintf(p,"%s%c%d",p, minus, t[a]);
else
sprintf(p,"%s%c%d",p, plus, t[a]);
}
print(p);
memset (p , 0, 2 * r +2);
pos --;
}
}
}

void create_print_combinations(int *t, int x, int n)
{
if(x == 0)
{
char p [2 * r + 2];
memset (p, 0, 2 * r +2);
for (int j=c;j>0;j--)
if(j == c)
sprintf(p, "%d", t[j]);
else
sprintf(p, "%s,%d", p,t[j]);
print_combi(p);
}
else
for (int i= n; i < r; i++)
{
t[x] = a[i];
create_print_combinations(t, x-1, i+1);
}
}
int main()
{
unsigned long int start=0, end=0;
printf ("\nEnter the a positive integer N:");
scanf("%d", &r);
start=time(NULL);
a = new int[r];
for (int i = 0;i<r;i++)
a[i]=i+1;
for(int j=1;j<=r;j++)
{
a1 = new int[j];
c=j;
create_print_combinations(a1, c, 0);
delete[] a1;
}
end=time(NULL);
printf("Total time taken = %llu\n" , end - start);
return 0;
}
```

As per the program logic I am computing the combinations as strings and the generating the absolute values of the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code for @SteveC's solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
void print_sum(int N, int sum_so_far, string as_a_string) {
        if(N) {
                ostringstream oss; oss << N;
                print_sum(N-1, sum_so_far+N, as_a_string + "+" + oss.str() + " ");
                print_sum(N-1, sum_so_far-N, as_a_string + "-" + oss.str() + " ");
                print_sum(N-1, sum_so_far, as_a_string);
        } else {  
                if (sum_so_far < 0) sum_so_far *= -1;
                cout << as_a_string << "\t= " << sum_so_far << endl;            }
}

int main() {
        print_sum(4, 0, "");
}
```

The output begins:

```
+4 +3 +2 +1     = 10
+4 +3 +2 -1     = 8
+4 +3 +2        = 9
+4 +3 -2 +1     = 6
+4 +3 -2 -1     = 4
+4 +3 -2        = 5
+4 +3 +1        = 8
+4 +3 -1        = 6
# .. and so on
```

Comment: Just pass N at the top and N-1 in the recursive call.  No need for x.  Also need to print absolute value on result.

Comment: @SteveC, +1 good points. Feel free to copy my code into your answer, including those changes. You should get the accepted answer! I'll be offline for the next few hours anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to what you are doing.  You want to add up a vector of N integers:

[ 1*k1, 2*k2, 3*k3 ... N*kN ]

where kx = -1, 0, +1.

There are 3^N combinations of kx for x=1..N.

Comment: I would like to understand the concept / approach you came up logically and required code implementation mapped to it [as provided below]. I think these are the things that I need to skill upon. Please provide some inputs in explicit manner and is there some details that talks about it. I have also seen concept like O(lonN) .. etc but really do not understand much of it.

Comment: You start with a vector [ 1, 2, 3, ... N ]
You took all combinations of the N elements which is equivalent to multiplying by 0 or +1.  Then you took all of the +1 elements and either add or subtract, which is the same as multiplying by +1 or -1.  I just noticed you could do this in one step.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is very similar to enumerating all combinations from "N choose 1" to "N choose N". I would suggest you search in google under the terms "Enumerate Combinations"

Here is one of the link I have found:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CombC.aspx

Comment: Yes, I am able to generate the combinations via create_print_combinations method coded - my issues is that I am not able to get the logic to print the absolute sums of all combinations: Like for Combi 1,2,3 : 1+2+3, 1+2-3, 1-2+3, 1-2-3. My logic breaks for a larger values say n = 10;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a logic on how to do it. Print all the binary digits of size `n-1` where `n` is the size (number of elements) of the respective combo. For example to do what you want to do for the combo [1,2,3,4] create all the binary combinations of `3` (n-1 = 3, here n = 4 elements). i.e.

```
when n = 3, the possible combinations are:
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Now run your combo in a for loop and inside it whenever you find a `0` do addition and whenever you find `1` do a subtraction. For example `000` would mean `1+2+3+4` and `101` would mean `1-2+3-4`.